# Error in lambda when running ridge

Tags: r, glmnet

I am running the following code but keep getting an error message. The code is from the ISLR website.

```
library(ISLR)
Hitters=na.omit(Hitters)
x=model.matrix(Salary~.,Hitters)[,-1]
y=Hitters$Salary
library(glmnet)
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=grid)
```

Error message:

```
Error in lambda < 0 : comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0,lambda=grid)
```

grid is a name of an R function (try '?grid'), but glmnet is expecting vector of lambda values.

If you run glmnet without providing a lambda sequence, the glmnet library uses its own heuristic to choose lambdas:

```
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0)
```

You can also provide your own sequence:

```
ridge.mod=glmnet(x,y,alpha=0, lambda=seq(10, 1000, 1))
```

but glmnet help advises against it.

> lambda     A user supplied lambda sequence. Typical usage is to have the
>   program compute its own lambda sequence based on nlambda and
>   lambda.min.ratio. Supplying a value of lambda overrides this. WARNING:
>   use with care. Avoid supplying a single value for lambda (for
>   predictions after CV use predict() instead). Supply instead a
>   decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms
>   starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than
>   compute a single fit.

(Note that 'seq(10, 1000, 1)' above is just an example to show the correct syntax.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Otto! It really solves my puzzle.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Thanks, Otto! I just clicked on the up arrow. unfortunately, due to my low reputation, it won't be publicly displayed. Sorry about that!

Comment: @ClaireCui you can't upvote because of your low rep, but please consider accepting the answer if you found it resolved your question.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp Just figured out how to accept an answer. Thanks!